# How can I override BBPress function bbp_has_topics() by adding a filter for this function in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

The "**bbp_has_topics**" function in "**public/wp-content/plugins/bbpress/includes/topics/template.php**" fetches the topics by "**meta_value**" in a "**Descending**" order. I need to override this behaviour to fetch the post by "**created date**" **without editing this file**. So is there a way to add a filter for this "bbp_has_topics". I added a filter in **functions.php** as below. But in the listing page the pagination links are not showing.

function mybbp_has_topics( $args = '') {
    $bbp = bbpress();

```
// Other defaults
$default_topic_search  = !empty( $_REQUEST['ts'] ) ? $_REQUEST['ts'] : false;
$default_show_stickies = (bool) ( bbp_is_single_forum() || bbp_is_topic_archive() ) && ( false === $default_topic_search );
$default_post_parent   = bbp_is_single_forum() ? bbp_get_forum_id() : 'any';

// The default forum query for most circumstances
$default = array(
    'post_type'      => bbp_get_topic_post_type(), // Narrow query down to bbPress topics
    'post_parent'    => $default_post_parent,      // Forum ID
    'meta_key'       => '_bbp_last_active_time',   // Make sure topic has some last activity time
    'orderby'        => 'date',              // 'meta_value', 'author', 'date', 'title', 'modified', 'parent', rand',
    'order'          => 'DESC',                    // 'ASC', 'DESC'
    'posts_per_page' => bbp_get_topics_per_page(), // Topics per page
    'paged'          => bbp_get_paged(),           // Page Number
    's'              => $default_topic_search,     // Topic Search
    'show_stickies'  => $default_show_stickies,    // Ignore sticky topics?
    'max_num_pages'  => false,                     // Maximum number of pages to show
);

$r = bbp_parse_args( $args, $default, 'has_topics' );

// Run the query
$bbp->topic_query = new WP_Query( $r );

return apply_filters( 'mybbp_has_topics', $bbp->topic_query->have_posts(), $bbp->topic_query );
```

}

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of this, you need to add your filter to the hook in bbp_has_topics.

Something like this function should be added as either in a new plugin or your theme's functions.php.

```
function mybbp_has_topics($have_posts, $topic_query){
    //your code
    $default_topic_search  = !empty( $_REQUEST['ts'] ) ? $_REQUEST['ts'] : false;
    $default_show_stickies = (bool) ( bbp_is_single_forum() || bbp_is_topic_archive() ) && ( false === $default_topic_search );
    $default_post_parent   = bbp_is_single_forum() ? bbp_get_forum_id() : 'any';

    // The default forum query for most circumstances
    $default = array(
        'post_type'      => bbp_get_topic_post_type(), // Narrow query down to bbPress topics
        'post_parent'    => $default_post_parent,      // Forum ID
        'meta_key'       => '_bbp_last_active_time',   // Make sure topic has some last activity time
        'orderby'        => 'date',              // 'meta_value', 'author', 'date', 'title', 'modified', 'parent', rand',
        'order'          => 'DESC',                    // 'ASC', 'DESC'
        'posts_per_page' => bbp_get_topics_per_page(), // Topics per page
        'paged'          => bbp_get_paged(),           // Page Number
        's'              => $default_topic_search,     // Topic Search
        'show_stickies'  => $default_show_stickies,    // Ignore sticky topics?
        'max_num_pages'  => false,                     // Maximum number of pages to show
);

    $r = bbp_parse_args( $args, $default, 'has_topics' );

    // Run the query
    $topic_query = new WP_Query( $r );
    return $topic_query;}

add_filter( 'bbp_has_topics', mybbp_has_topics, 99, 2);
```

the parameter $topic_query contains the query that was made in bbp_has_topics.